# why is findOneAndUpdate not updating in the DB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a project using the mern stack. I'm trying to update a project from my frontend to my backend. When I update it it will return success but when I check the database nothing is updated? I'm trying to update the product with the prodID that is entered in the frontend

This is my post route

```
router.post("/updateStock", (req, res) => {
    const prodID = req.body.prodID

    const product = new Product(req.body)

    Product.findOneAndUpdate(prodID, { new: true }, {returnOriginal: false}, function(err, products) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("err", err);
          res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
          console.log("success");
          res.send(product);
        }
    });

});
```

This is my schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Product = mongoose.model(
  "Product",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    manufacturer: String,
    price: String,
    catergory: String,
    quantity: String,
    prodID: String, 
    images: Array
  })
);

module.exports = Product;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Mongoose Docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)

1st:

You added filter as a string, however it should've been an object like below

```
const filter = {prodID: req.body.prodID}
```

2nd:

no need to instantiate the Product schema, use the update object

```
const update = req.body
```

3rd:
You used the same option, also `new:true` took the place of the update object

> returnOriginal: false is equivalent to new: true

4th:

Use promise not callbacks, however you have a typo in the callback you called `products` and you sent `product`

```
Product.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {new: true}).then((product) => {
      console.log("success");
      res.send(product);
}).catch(err => {
     console.log("err", err);
     res.status(500).send(err);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the new updated body to `findOneAndUpdate`. The `findOneAndUpdate` is expecting `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate( filter, update, options )`. The code should be like this:-

```
    router.post("/updateStock", (req, res) => {

    const product = new Product(req.body);
    const filter = {prodID: req.body.prodID}

    Product.findOneAndUpdate(filter, product, { new: true, returnOriginal: false}, function(err, products) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("err", err);
          res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
          console.log("success");
          res.send(product);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get this error : err MongoError: Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Schema  =>

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options)
```

Pass Update object